# If Statement Simple

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, var

Is there a way to make this ELIF statement simplier, by the way this code doesnt work.
The variable that change is APPOINTMENT

```
elif (rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and 'TAL'  in appointment) or
        (rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and 'IQQ'  in appointment) or
        (rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and 'ANF'  in appointment) or
        (rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and 'MJS'  in appointment) or
        (rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and 'QTV'  in appointment) or
        (rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and 'SVE'  in appointment) or
        (rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and 'PMC'  in appointment) or
        (rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and 'CHB'  in appointment):
        df.at[idx,'REBATE'] = round(int(monto_neto)*0.35)
```

Comment: `(p and q) or (p and r) <=> p and (q or r)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `any` for the last condition which becomes a one-liner:

```
elif rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and any(x in appointment for x in ['TAL','IQQ','rest of strings to match...']):
```

Comment: What is the opposite for ANY() ?

Comment: but that brings me all!, in the example any(x in appointment for x in ['TAL', .. i need the opposite, like NOT ANY? is possible?

Comment: just `not any` then: true only if no substring is contained in appointment

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
elif rut == '80010900-0' and agental_launch != "" and any(elem in appointment for elem in ['TAL','IQQ','ANF','MJS','QTV','SVE','PMC','CHB']):
     df.at[idx,'REBATE'] = round(int(monto_neto)*0.35)
```

Comment: Hey Vasilis, what is the opposite for ANY?